# Code signature and steps to write public static void main(String args[] )

Tags: java, webservice-client, wsdl2java

Using `WSDL2Java` the "WeatherService" WSDL to Client side code is generated successfully.

In which java file and methods should be used for  the main class be written to access the and execute the process ?

- `WeatherServiceCallbackHandler.java`
- `WeatherServiceStub.java`

I presume ther should be some standard signature code steps to follow and access the methods avaliable in the WSDL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In neither. You shouldn't touch the generated code at all.
You class should make calls to the generated code in order to 
interact with the web-service.

Normally you would instantiate a service locator and use it to get a stub
implementation.  You could then use the stub directly.

So in short, your main method should be inside a separate class altogether.

See code below for how to use the stub implementation generated by wsdl2java:

```
package com.axis.weather;

import static com.axis.weather.WeatherServiceStub.*;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Weather w = new Weather();
        w.setHowMuchRain(2.2f);

        SetWeather wrapper = new SetWeather();
        wrapper.setArgs0(w);

        try {
            WeatherServiceStub stub = new WeatherServiceStub(); // will use http://localhost:8080/axis2/services/WeatherService.WeatherServiceHttpSoap12Endpoint/
            stub.setWeather(wrapper);
        } catch (java.rmi.RemoteException re) {
            re.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Regards
Yusuf

Comment: Hi
Could u explain with code implementation ...please with  
This is simple WeatherService example present in pojo guide, Could u
please use WSDL2java  generate the code and provide me the complete example

Also please provide the switches used on WSDL2java ( -ss,=g ....) u have used


with regards

Comment: When you use WSDL2Java, it creates a src folder as well as an ANT build script.  Run the build script and include the client jar file in your project.  Se my original post for how to use the generated stub.  The command I used for wsdl2java is : wsdl2java.bat -o output -s -p com.axis.weather -uri http://localhost:8080/axis2/services/WeatherService?wsdl

Comment: Hey Thx for the reply. still have some more Questions

I i provide a WSDL to client of mine or if any body provides a WSDL to me,should there be a sample code given along with to access the methods.

Comment: Hi  

ServiceEndpoint is a must as u said,but wouldnt the person be confused with several methods ???
is this ant code same as u'r cmds

<axis2-wsdl2java 
   wsdlfilename="${WSDLOP1}/${WSDLFILE}?wsdl" 
   output="c:/temp/CLIENT/"
   serversideinterface="true"
   serverside="true" 
   
   />